# SQL interval with subqueries

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, intervals

I want filter records oldes for some date and this SQL is not working:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE UPDATED_ON + INTERVAL (SELECT B.DAYS FROM B.TABLE2 
                             WHERE B.NAME = 'Tmp') DAY < SYSDATE;
```

But this SQL is working because have constant 2 in ''. How I can do this with subqueries instead constant?

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE UPDATED_ON + INTERVAL '2' DAY < SYSDATE;
```

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Their date/time functions are very different.

Comment: I am using oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it like this:

```
select UPDATED_ON
       , UPDATED_ON  +  (SELECT t2.DAYS FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t2.NAME = 'Tmp') 
FROM TABLE1 
WHERE UPDATED_ON +  (SELECT t2.DAYS FROM TABLE2 t2 WHERE t2.NAME = 'Tmp')  < SYSDATE;
```

Here is a demo:

> [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=495436e88f1caacfd07163e2c01ff55f)

Answer (score 3):

Either use

```
WHERE
   UPDATED_ON 
      + (SELECT B.DAYS FROM B.TABLE2 WHERE B.NAME = 'Tmp') * INTERVAL '1' DAY < SYSTIMESTAMP
```

or

```
WHERE
   UPDATED_ON 
      + NUMTODSINTERVAL((SELECT B.DAYS FROM B.TABLE2 WHERE B.NAME = 'Tmp'), 'day') < SYSTIMESTAMP
```

or

```
WHERE
   UPDATED_ON 
      + (SELECT B.DAYS FROM B.TABLE2 WHERE B.NAME = 'Tmp') < SYSDATE
```

Comment: This is a great hack. I created a new meta table where I update that no. of days in it. 
I am using this as subquery and multiply with interval. Works like charm

Answer (score 1):

You could write this as:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where updated_on < (
    select systimestamp - t2.days * interval '1' day from table2 t2 where t2.name = 'Tmp'
)
```

Alternatively, if `updated_on` is a `date`rather than a `timestamp`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where updated_on < (
    select sysdate - t2.days from table2 t2 where t2.name = 'Tmp'
)
```

Note that this will fail if there is more than one row in `table2` whose `name` is `'Tmp'`.

Comment: Yes, I have more than one row in table2

Comment: I prefer not mixing `DATE` and `INTERVAL` types. Either use `TIMESTAMP` (i.e. `SYSTIMESTAMP`) and `INTERVAL` or `DATE` and numbers (i.e. number of days). You can mix them but when you are not familiar with the implicite conversions then the result may not be as expected.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: thanks, that's a good point. I updated my answer.